# how to fix PHP Notice: Undefined index (don't show 'what's file error')

Tags: php, wordpress, undefined

I got too many for this warning debug in wordpress ver 4.2.4
but they didnt showed which file gave this warning.

`debug.log` show only this message.

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 4
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: 36
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$unread
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: topicname
```

How can I find and fix this warning?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/3933332

Comment: Also that we are really able to help you, you need to show us the relevant code.

Comment: @Rizier123 The point here is that the OP doesn't know what code this error pertains to because the log doesn't tell.

Comment: @deceze I'm not a wordpress expert, but you mean that the error log doesn't even contain the line number + file ?

Comment: @Rizier123 Apparently not. I'd guess Wordpress is adding its own error handler and log processing... (not that I'm a Wordpress expert either, god forbid, but I wouldn't be surprised).

Comment: I already fix other error if it have ":in /directory/file.php".  But I can not find .php file because my log show only that msg.

Comment: @deceze I would guess, then this is one of the *most helpful error logs* :]

Comment: @Rizier123 Well, Wordpress is one of the Most Helpful Softwares™... Ask anyone who needs to pwn a few boxen, they all agree... ;o)

Comment: I think all error from simplepress plugin but I don't know what file get error.

Answer (score -1):

you can use following php code in index file according to your need

// Turn off all error reporting

error_reporting(0);

OR

// Report all errors except E_NOTICE

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);